# Python - Call Object until Object returns true

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way I can call self.bestSpot(...) until it return True. I am working on a Tic-Tac-Toe game and I want the computerTurn() to call bestSpot() until one of the bestSpots() works at which point the computer will take its turn and the human can make the next move.

```
def computerTurn(self):
    botPawn = self.getCurrentPlayerPawn()
    if botPawn == 'O':
        enemyPawn = 'X'
    elif botPawn == 'X':
        enemyPawn = 'O'

    while True:
        self.bestSpot(enemyPawn, 0, 1, 2)
        self.bestSpot(enemyPawn, 3, 4, 5)
        self.bestSpot(enemyPawn, 6, 7, 8)

def bestSpot(self, enemyPawn, num0, num1, num2):
    if self.placeHolder[num0] == enemyPawn and self.placeHolder[num2] == enemyPawn:
        self.playerTurn(str(num1))
    elif self.placeHolder[num0] == enemyPawn and self.placeHolder[num1] == enemyPawn:
        self.playerTurn(str(num2))
    elif self.placeHolder[num1] == enemyPawn and self.placeHolder[num2] == enemyPawn:
        self.playerTurn(str(num0))
    else:
        return(False)

def playerTurn(self, button_name):
    for i in self.buttons:
        if button_name == i.objectName() and int(button_name) in self.placeHolder:
            self.moves = self.moves + 1
            player = self.getCurrentPlayerPawn()
            self.buttons[int(i.objectName())].setText(player)
            self.placeHolder[:] = [player if x == int(i.objectName()) else x for x in self.placeHolder]
            self.buttons[int(i.objectName())].setEnabled(False)
            self.checkWin(player)
            self.changePlayer()
```

Comment: *bestSpot* never returns *True*. In 3 (out of 4) cases, it returns *None*, which also evaluates to *False*.

Comment: The issue I am having is it looping. It never breaks the While True loop

Comment: Do you mean `isBestSpot()`? If yes, rewrite it so it returns True or False. Then you can write `while not isBestSpot()`. And yes, if you write `while True`, it will never break, so don't do that :-)